# Prolog subtract value not working

Tags: prolog

I got this knowledge base:

```
bottle(b1).
bottle(b2).
bottle(b3).
bottle(b4).

full(bottle(b1),100).
full(bottle(b2),150).
full(bottle(b3),300).
full(bottle(b4),400).


consume(bottle(X),Milliliter) :-
   full(bottle(X),Y),
   Milliliter=<Y,
   Y-10.
```

So I want to use the consume predicate, and I want to reduce the value assigned to full as much as the value which is getting consumed. Is it allowed to subtract from static values and how could I work around this problem to achieve only the value true if there hasn't been consumed the bottle yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to "update" the KB when you call "consume", you will have to retract and assert the fact, for example...

```
% Use this to add the initial facts (if you don;t have a clause to do this, prolog complains about modifying static clauses...)
addfacts :-
    asserta(full(bottle(b1),100)),
    asserta(full(bottle(b2),150)),
    asserta(full(bottle(b3),300)),
    asserta(full(bottle(b4),400)).

consume(bottle(X), Millis) :-
    % Retract the current state of the bottle
    retract(full(bottle(X), V)),
    % Calculate the new Millis after consumption
    Y is V - Millis,
    % Check it was possible (there should be 0 or more millis left after)
    Y >= 0,
    % Add the new fact
    asserta(full(bottle(X), Y)).
```

Now in prolog, you can do...

```
1 ?- addfacts.
true.

2 ?- full(bottle(b1), X).
X = 100.

3 ?- consume(bottle(b1), 10).
true.

4 ?- full(bottle(b1), X).
X = 90 .
```